# How to read a csv file in shiny an load to the global Environment?

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I have this shiny app. You can run it and try it.

This application helps me to read a csv files and render a Table with the information of the csv file.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)



ui <- shinyUI(
  
  fluidPage(
    textInput("fname","File name: ",value="data.csv"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text"),
    actionButton("chck_file", "Check for file"),
    actionButton("create_file", "Create file"),
    
    #Data Table 
    tableOutput("table1")
    
  ))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Listens for click from element with ID=chck_file
  observeEvent(input$chck_file,{
    # Check if file exists
    if ( file.exists( isolate({input$fname}) ) ){
      # Display text
      output$text <- renderText({ paste("File exists in: ",getwd(),sep="") })
      
      data <- input$fname
      print(data)
      df = read.csv(data)
      output$table1 <- renderTable(df)
      
      
      
    }
    else{
      output$text <- renderText({ paste("No such file in: ",getwd(),sep="") })
    }
  })
  
  # Listens for click from element with ID=create_file
  observeEvent(input$create_file,{
    # Create file
    file.create(isolate({input$fname}))
  })
})



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**I want to be able to load the dataframe that I am reading in the global environment of RStudio, how can I do this?**

I tried with this operator **<<-**

```
df <<- read.csv(data)
Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'
```

Also I tried with this solution, but only works when I stop my shiny app

```
data <- reactiveValues()


output$contents <- renderText({    
      if(is.null(input$file1))return()
      inFile <- input$file1
      data2<-read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  assign('data',data2,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  print(summary(data))
 })
```

And I don't want to stop my session in order to see my data frame in the global env

Answer (score 0):

```
df <<- read.csv(data)
Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'
```

The operator `<<-` does not mean assignment in the global environment. Rather, it means "non-local assignment". When you do `x <<- 2`, R searches for `x` in the current environment, then in the parent environment if it does not find it, etc, until the global environment. If `x` is never found then R performs the assignment in the global environment.

Here `df` is found: this is the name of a function in the `stats` package. And one cannot change its value. So you have to use another name. But I don't know whether this will have an effect before closing the app, I didn't try.

## EDIT

Yes this works, but you have to refresh the environment pane while the app is running (click on the circular arrow in the environment pane).

Comment: Which one works for you? None of the two solutions works for me

Comment: When I tried to refresh the environment pane this message appears "R Session Aborted"